# Get the text file content line and display it in console using c#

Tags: c#

currently, I'm a freshman student, and my teacher tasked me with creating a simple C# console system.

I'm using a text file/notepad as the database for my system data because we are not allowed to use any other databases.

Now, I'm having trouble figuring out how to display the line coordinates of the text file content. I plan to use them as IDs for referencing the edit and delete functions.

And I'm using visual studio 2012

Example text file data:

Maple,Apple
Peanut,Coconut

My goal output on console:

| Line | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maple | Apple |
| 2 | Peanut | Coconut |

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is. What exactly about reading files are you having problems with? Do you know how to get the content of a file in general, or determine "lines" from a string?

Comment: It seems like you’re trying to use a .csv format. You mentioned you can only use text files, so I would just use the csv (comma separated values) in a txt file. Here’s the Wikipedia page for csv:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: Make small steps: 1) read the file as separate lines; 2) split each line into "columns" ; 3) display it

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really ask a question, so I just made a program to do what you were describing.

For reference, there are *two* ways to get data from a file, the first being `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path.txt");`

```cs
using System.IO;
// Gets the whole of the data, and shoves it into a string[]
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("example.txt");

// Example File (example.txt):
// line,b,c
// 1,Maple,Apple
// 2,Peanut,Coconut

// What `data` should look like:
// line,b,c
// 1,Maple,Apple
// 2,Peanut,Coconut
```

The second being `System.IO.StreamReader`, which reads the file via the stream, and must be disposed after use, by using `StreamReader.Dispose()`:

```cs
using System.IO;

StreamReader stream = new StreamReader("example.txt");

string[] data = new string[3];

// I'll use the line length from earlier
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    data[i] = stream.ReadLine();

}

// Make sure to dispose!
stream.Dispose();

// The output (of printing the array) should be the same as the previous example.
```

Now that you know how to read a file, the rest should really just be `Console.Write()` and `Console.WriteLine()` formatting.

I hope this helps!

(Yes, I actually wrote a program for this question, here it is:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

class SpreadsheetConsole {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("example.txt");
        // Get the names of each of the columns
        string[] columnNames = lines[0].Split(',');
        // Get the number of columns
        int columnCount = columnNames.Length;

        // Create a 2D array to store the data, to make it easier to index
        string[,] data = new string[lines.Length, columnCount];

        // Loop through each line
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
            // Split the line into the individual values
            string[] values = lines[i].Split(',');
            // Loop through each value and add it to the data array
            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                data[i, j] = values[j];
            }
        }

        // Render the spreadsheet
        RenderSpreadSheet(data);

    }
    
    public static void RenderSpreadSheet(string[,] data) {

        // Get the number of rows and columns
        int rowCount = data.GetLength(0);
        int columnCount = data.GetLength(1);

        // We're gonna style it like .md tables

        // | Column 1 | Column 2 |
        // |----------|----------|
        // | Value 1  | Value 2  |
        // | Value 3  | Value 4  |

        // I'm hardcoding the first row, don't do this, figure out a smarter way to do it!
        Console.WriteLine($"| {data[0, 0]} | {data[0, 1]} | {data[0, 2]} |");
        Console.WriteLine("| --- | --- | --- |");
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            // Loop through each column

            if (i == 0) continue;

            Console.Write("| ");
            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                
                // Print the value
                Console.Write(data[i, j] + " | ");

            }
            // Print a new line
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
}
```

This problem looked so interesting, I just had to!)

Comment: Ah dang it, I did the "why teach me just give me code to copy paste" stackoverflow meme, didn't I?

Comment: Instead of explicitly calling Dispose, use a `using` block

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yes, thanks for the comment!